# Not Enough Space To Show Ad

Tags: android, xml, layout, admob

Here is my XML layout code which gives the error of not enough space. Seems like the width is not big enough which I find extremely strange.
Not Enough Space To Show Add!  Want <480, 85> Has <432, 676> This is the error im gettin in the logcat.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/backgr2"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="Some Text" />

    Maybe this gridview takes too much of the screen?
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="131dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bakgr"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >
    </GridView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gridView1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:text="Some Text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state"
         />

    This is the adview which cannot be displayed for I dont know what reason!
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                     ads:adUnitId="XXXX"
                     ads:testDevice="TEST_EMULATOR"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Yeah.. Please Help

Comment: I tried android:layout_width="wrap_content" as well as moving as other object a lot higher but nothing seems to change the error numbers.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the RelativeLayout Padding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the RelativeLayout padding specified in the root element. It affects the AdView as well, and this is the reason you are getting this error.

Move the padding specifically to the elements that need it, or wrap those elements in an additional LinearLayout and give it the padding it needs.

Answer (score 1):

just remove

```
       android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

from relative layout and your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

It is the left and right padding of the RelativeLayout.
Remove that and it will work.